# What Will Be Considered Opinion Based

Tags: discussion, support

There are questions that asked stuff like how should you store coffee beans and stuff where answers may vary. One of my questions was that whether coffee should be served warm or hot. That question was similar, except with only two possible choices. Yet a user says that my question is opinion-based. Now I am confused on what types of questions will be opinion-based. So my question is, which types of questions would be considered opinion-based?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What flavor is "preferable", strikes me as primarily opinion based. However, asking about the general types of coffee flavors should be encouraged. When describing a flavor or taste there are going to be some adjectives that may not be viewed the same way by everyone reading them. If one person says a coffee is "bitter", that's not necessarily opinion based. Saying that "because it's bitter it is no good", however, is.

It's hard to mark a defining line, but it's a line that we can define as a community, and shouldn't try to pin down right away (though, for the most part, I think it will be fairly obvious when someone crosses it).

Other examples:

### Opinion based

- A robusta is **better** than an arabica
- Do you **prefer** a french press or a pour-over?
- Bitter coffee's taste bad

### Not opinion based

- This coffee has a bitter aftertaste
- Coffee *A* is more bitter than coffee *B* (somewhat opinion based, but how else do you describe it when making a comparison? this really depends on the question, I think)